# how can I use killtimer to finish Qtimer;

Tags: qt, qtimer

```
timer->start(1000); 
int n=timer->timerId(); 
qDebug()<<n; 
killTimer(n);
```

timer id 5 is not valid for object 0x7ffd2a5463d0 (MainWindow, MainWindow), timer has not been killed

Answer (score 2):

[`killTimer()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#killTimer) only stop timers started using the [`startTimer()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer) method. In your case if you use [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) then you must use the stop method:

```
timer->stop();
```